# Creating a new record from the first item in list

Tags: filemaker

I have a table which contains a long list of products. Each product has both a sku and a style number. The stye number is common to a set of sku numbers. For example, a North Face Jacket will have a general style number and each size and color will have individual sku numbers. I need to take the first instance of the style number in a very long list and create a new record in a separate table. That way I can set a relationship to hook all the separate sku numbers to the main style number. I'm not a Filemaker pro so any advice on how to do this would be appreciated. I assume there's a way to loop through the list and create a new record from the first instance of a new style number?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a snap in FileMaker.

First, as always when manipulating a lot of data, **Create a backup of your filemaker file:**

```
File > Save a copy as...
```

Be sure that you don't select clone as your type, or you will end up with no data.

**These instructions assume you have two tables, as follows:**

product (has records)

- id
- sku
- style

style (empty)

- id
- style

**Create a relationship**

```
File > Manage Database > Define Relationship
```

- Drag out a relationship from product::style to style::style.
- Double click on the equal sign.
- On the *style* side of the relationship, check 'Allow creation of records in this table via this relationship.'
- Click *OK* twice.

**Write a script to create the records**

`Scripts > Manage Scripts`

- Click "New"
- Recreate the following script:

[image: FileMaker script to create style records]

If you have any trouble, just write back here. I added comments, so hopefully everything is easy and understandable.

And don't forget to back up your data first! Good luck.